# Is there a parameterized version of the Query-Class in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, jpa

When I use EntityManager.createQuery() I always end up with a SupressWarning Annotation to suppress the uncheckt parameter conversion to a generic / parameterized List<...>

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
Query query = em.createQuery("FROM Person");

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Person> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

Is there any possibility to get around this?